# VBScript error with temperature parsing

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing

So I have been trying to parse the temperature from weather.com and have managed to do it, but now I am stuck trying to save the temperature to a file (temperature.txt). I feel like this should work but it returns the error:

```
Line: 11   Char: 1   Error: Type mismatch: 'Write'   Code: 800A000D
```

This is my code please help!!!

```
Dim nm, em, FSO, oFile

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = false
xmlDoc.load("http://xml.weather.com/weather/local/USUT0225?cc=*&unit=farenheit&dayf=0")
Set temp = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("/weather/dayf/day/part/t")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("temperature.txt", 2, True)

oFile.Write(temp)
oFile.Close

Set oFile = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: When I check the type of `temp` it returns `Nothing` which is why you are getting a type mismatch. Need to figure out why the `Set temp` is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further the answer since I was having an issue with your node I tried something like this

```
Dim nm, em, FSO, oFile

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = false
xmlDoc.load("http://xml.weather.com/weather/local/USUT0225?cc=*&unit=farenheit&dayf=0")
Set temp = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode ("/weather/cc/tmp")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("temperature.txt", 2, True)

oFile.Write(temp.text)
oFile.Close

Set oFile = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

While checking the type of `temp` it keep returning `Nothing`. I went to look at the XML file via the link and I couldnt follow `"/weather/dayf/day/part/t"` you had there ( Might be because I'm in Canada and was getting redirected). Either way I updated the node you were looking for to `"/weather/cc/tmp"` and outputted the `.text` to the file. As of right this moment the contents of my text file are `79`

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
Set temp = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("/weather/dayf/day/part/t")
```

assigns a (node) object to temp (great variable name, btw). The .Write method of the TextStream object can't serialize objects, it can write only strings. So .Write the node's XML content:

```
oFile.Write temp.xml
```

(and loose those [()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx))

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understood what you were saying but didn't know how to format it. But thanks anyways it now works!